# After closing lid I still must press power button to turn screen on

Tags: laptop, windows-10, display, sleep, power

On my Windows 10 64-bit machine, the "when I close the lid" settings is set to:

- On battery: Do nothing
- Plugged in: Do nothing

Yet after I closed the lid and open it again, I still need to press the power button to turn the screen on. Why is it like that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

In **Power Options**, click your power plan's `Change plan settings` -> `Change advanced power settings` -> click `Change settings that are currently unavailable` -> `Power buttons and lid` -> `Lid close action` -> select `Do nothing`. `OK` and `Save changes`.